# countability of set of well-formed formulas

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

Here is the question:

Define the set WFF as follows--

a) Every element in set $A = \{s_1, s_2, ...\}$ is in WFF. $A$ is countably infinite.

b) If $a$ is in WFF, so is $(\neg a)$. If $n$ and $m$ are in WFF, so is $(n \lor m)$.

c) No other elements are in WFF.

Show that WFF is countable.

Attempt at a solution:
I was thinking it might be possible to show by induction that $S_i$, the set of all expressions with $i$ symbols, is countable, and then show that the union of all such countable $S_i$'s is also countable (which I know how to do). However, I'm unsure of how to proceed for the first part -- would it even be necessary to show that the set of all expressions with $i$ symbols is countable, as per the parentheses in the rules, it isn't possible to have an expression with, say, $i = 3$ symbols, or am I confused?

Another thing I am having trouble with is that there doesn't seem to be any restriction from the criteria against infinitely long strings/logical sequences (that would make WFF, to my knowledge, not countable). I believe this is the right approach, but I am unable to justify that to myself.

Comment: What assumptions do you have on $A$? Just countability?

Comment: Yes, A is countably infinite. I am adding that to the question now!

Comment: Just show that the set of all propositional variables is countable, then each $S_i, i \geq 4$ is countable by induction (because you have finitely many logical symbols). Maybe show there are no wffs of length 2 or 3.

Comment: Every string will be finite.  You can only apply part b) finitely many times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This style of definition can be confusing if you see it for the first time in a source that does not bother to explain very carefully how it should be understood.

What part (c) means is that $WFF$ is defined to be the **smallest possible** set that satisfies the conditions in parts (a) and (b).

Before this is actually a definition we need to prove that there *is* such a unique smallest possible set:

Let's call a set that satisfies (a) and (b) *good*. Consider now the set
$$ W = \{ x \mid x\text{ is a member of every good set}\} $$
It is now easy enough to prove that $W$ is good, and that $W$ is a subset of every good set. This latter property means that $W$ is smaller than every other good set, so it is actually the set $\mathit{WFF}$ being definied!

Since the set of all *finite* strings over $A\cup\{{\neg},{\vee},{(},{)}\}$ is good (this is easy to verify), we can conclude that it is a subset of $\mathit{WFF}$, and therefore $\mathit{WFF}$ contains only finite stings.

---

If you know some axiomatic set theory, you will notice that I've swept a problem under the rug, namely showing that $W$ exists as a set at all -- above I've defined it using unrestricted comprehension. But as long as there exists *at least one* good set (and I've just argued that the set of finite strings is such a good set), then we can see that $W$ is a subclass of this set, and is therefore a set itself.

Comment: Thank you so much, this clarifies a ton. Regarding verifying that the set of finite strings over the symbols is good, I was wondering if you might have suggestions for a starting point (it seems that one could just argue that if a and b are in WFF and are finite, then a union b must also be finite (and have, specifically, the length of a + b + 1) (or whatever other logical operation))?

Comment: @4313: There's nothing to it, really -- just notice that each $s_i$ is a finite string (namely it has length $1$ because we've declared the $s_i$s to be symbols), and whenever $a$ and $b$ are finite strings, then $(\neg a)$ and $(a\lor b)$ are both finite strings too.

Answer (score 2):

S = A $\cup$ {$\neg,\lor,$(,) } is a countable set of symbols.
Sf, the set of finite strings of symbols from S, is countable.
As WWF, the set of well formed formulas, is a subset of Sf,
WWF is countable.

Comment: Why is $S_f$ countable? Could you elaborate? (maybe suggest a bijection between $S_f$ and $\mathbb{N}$)

Comment: The set of strings of length k is countable.  Altogether there is countablely  many countable sets.