# On the countability of the set of well-formed formulae

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, propositional-calculus

I read an answer to this [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2634408/countability-of-set-of-well-formed-formulas) on MathSE, but the details of the argument are still hazy to me.

One of the users suggested that the set of WFFs is countable because:

> S = $A \cup \{\neg,\lor,\land, (, )\}$ is a **countable set** of symbols ($A$ is a countably infinite set of propositional variables).
> $S_f$, the set of finite strings of symbols from $S$, is countable.
> As the set of all well-formed formulae is a **subset** of $S_f$, it is countable.

My question: **Why is $S_f$ countable?** Could you suggest a bijection between $S_f$ and $\mathbb{N}$? (for if $S_f$ is countable, it must be countably infinite)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** As $S$ is countable, you can get a bijection $f:S\rightarrow P$ where $P$ is the set of all prime numbers. Now, if $a_1\dots a_n$ is a string of simbols in $S$, you can codify it with the number $f(a_1)\times...\times f(a_n)$.

Comment: I agree, and this is a brilliant idea. How does it show countability though?

Answer (score 1):

Let $S = \{a_n \mid n \in {\Bbb N}\}$ be a countable alphabet. The set of finite strings of symbols from $S$ is the [free monoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_monoid) on $S$, usually denoted by $S^*$.
Now the map $f:S^* \to {\Bbb N}$ where $f(a_{i_1}a_{i_2} \dotsm a_{i_n})$ is the binary integer $10^{i_1}10^{i_2} \dotsm 10^{i_n}$ is clearly injective. Thus $S^*$ is countable.

Comment: What's a monoid? I haven't seen this before. Could you fill in more details?

Comment: I added a link to the definition of a free monoid. A monoid is simply a set equipped with an associative operation which admits an identity.